# How can i manage paypal account country wise in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to apply multiple paypal account in wordpress county wise. when a user visit store from a specific country and visitor proceed to checkout then visitor pay in that country related paypal account. I am using below code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta' );
function woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $address = $order->get_billing_address_1();
  update_post_meta( $order_id, '_alternative_paypal_email', $email );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_paypal_args( $paypal_args, $order ) {
  $email = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_alternative_paypal_email', true );
  if ( !empty( $email ) ) {
    $paypal_args['business'] = $email;
  }
  return $paypal_args;
}
```

Comment: I have manage this by implementing the plugin that do same as i want.